# Get style text after selector was updated from script

Tags: javascript, css

I have a style tag with

```
.first { color: red } .other { color: blue }
```

Then I'm changing first selector there

```
style.sheet.cssRules[0].selectorText = '.second'
```

Now I want to get the full updated css style

```
.second { color: red } .other { color: blue }
```

But instead of it I'm getting tag's original content.

**How should I fix the code to get new styles?**

```js
var style = document.getElementById('style')
style.sheet.cssRules[0].selectorText = '.second'
console.log(style.textContent)
```

```html
<style id="style">.first { color: red } .other { color: blue }</style>

<p class="first">First</p>
<p class="second">Second</p>
<p class="other">Other</p>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Did you run the code snippet? That's not relevant to this question.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, 1. I do not understand why you give link to [that page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule/style)? 2. On the [page about selectorText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule/selectorText) it's written _"gets and sets the selectors"._ 3. If you run the snippet, you'll see that the `.second` is red and the `.first` is black, so this code does change selector at least in Chrome.

Comment: my bad - removed the comment. I've totally misread the DOCS.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, actually seems like it really doesn't work if `@media` is involved...

Comment: @Qwertiy interesting find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the `cssText` of each rule.

```js
var style = document.getElementById('style')
style.sheet.cssRules[0].selectorText = '.second'

let newStyle = [...style.sheet.cssRules].reduce((acc, curr)=>acc + curr.cssText, "");
console.log(newStyle);
```

```html
<style id="style">.first { color: red } .other { color: blue }</style>

<p class="first">First</p>
<p class="second">Second</p>
<p class="other">Other</p>
```